# The range of any continuous function from $[0, \omega_1] \times [0, \omega_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is countable

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

I came across this question:
“Prove that the range of any continuous function from $[0, \omega_1] \times [0, \omega_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is countable”
I’m quite new to ordinals and I’m having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around this statement, much less the proof of it. Here, $[0,\omega_1]$ is the second uncountable, so im very unclear on how its range could possible be countable? In this problem $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard topology and the product has the product topology. Any intuition or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen the proof that the range of any continuous function $[0, \omega_1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is countable?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for that correction! Also no, I have not seen that proof, do you know where I might find it to study it?

Comment: Oh wait, is it because any continuous function from $[0, \omega_1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is constant on some tail?

Comment: I don't know of a reference off the top of my head; but the basic idea is: for each positive integer $n$, there exists $\alpha_n < \omega_1$ such that $|f(\beta) - f(\omega_1)| < \frac{1}{n}$ whenever $\alpha_n < \beta \le \omega_1$.  Therefore, if we let $\alpha := \sup_{n} \alpha_n$ (with an application of axiom of choice in here), then $f(\beta) = f(\omega_1)$ whenever $\alpha < \beta \le \omega_1$.  So, the range of $f$ is equal to $f([0, \alpha]) \cup \{ f(\omega_1) \}$ is countable since $\alpha$ is countable.

Comment: Ah, that was incredibly helpful, thank you so much! Ordinals have been very confusing for me, so thank you for taking the time to explain this to me!

Comment: @DanielSchepler I’ve tried using your above proof to mimic a similar proof for the $[0, \omega_1] \times [0, \omega_1]$ case, but I run into an issue that I don’t know how to resolve: if you take such points $\alpha_n$, then it might be the case that the first coordinate of some points is $\omega_1$ and the second coordinate of some points is also $\omega_1$ by definition of the lexicographic order, so that the limit of these points might be $(\omega_1,\omega_1)$. Do you have any hints on how to remedy this?

Comment: I don't see what the lexicographic product order has to do with anything, since you said you're using the product topology on $[0, \omega_1] \times [0, \omega_1]$.  So, that means that the basic open neighborhoods of $(\omega_1, \omega_1)$ would be of the form $(\alpha, \omega_1] \times (\beta, \omega_1]$.

Comment: I believe I was very confused, I was under the impression you would need this order to define your sequence of $\alpha_n$’s, but this is not the case, you’re using continuity of f, specifically continuity of f at the point $(\omega_1, \omega_1)$ to get these basic open nhoods and this to get this sequence of points. Is this correct?